# Define variables for internal app states in angular.js controller to show/hide elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I ran into this problem in several situations, but let's use one example here. Say I have an interaction flow of form submission. It is composed of three steps, for example, data input step, double checking step, and confirmation step. In each step, I will display different relevant information along with the form using ng-show/ng-hide. The way I do it now is to define the flow like a state machine and use a internal variable (e.g. currState) to represent the current state, and modify the variable when switching to a different state. In ng-show/ng-hide, I check the currState variable to show/hide the element. Something looks like this:

In my Angular controller:

```
$scope.currState = 'DATA_INPUT';
```

In my HTML:

```
<div ng-show="currState == 'DATA_INPUT'"></div>
```

I'm wondering if there is any native support for this kind of use case or best practices/patterns, since the way I'm doing now is error-prone and not very flexible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngSwitch` for this:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

So:

```
<div ng-switch on="state">
        <div ng-switch-default>Fist. <button ng-click="state='second'">Next</button></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="second">Second. <button ng-click="state='final'">Next</button></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="final">Final</div>

</div>
```